# Consulta SQL unificando 3 tabelas

Tags: sql, inner-join

Tenho 4 tabelas que preciso uni-las em uma unica consulta onde o resultado seja:

```
nome |COUNT(terrenosDeCadaID)|COUNT(conversasDeCadaID)
joao |         2             |       3
maria|         1             |       2
```

As tabelas estão assim:

```
users
id|nome
1 |joao
2 |maria

terrenos
id|idterreno |iduser(mesmo que id da tabela users)
1 |    20    |  1
2 |    21    |  1
3 |    22    |  2

conversas
id|idterreno|msg|iduser(mesmo que id da tabela users)
1 |   20    | a |  1
2 |   20    | b |  1
3 |   21    | c |  1
4 |   22    | d |  2
5 |   22    | d |  2
```

Tentei fazer com INNER JOIN, mas ainda sou iniciante, e não consegui, quando adicionei o conversas deu errado, abaixo o que tentei:

```
SELECT nome, COUNT(t.iduser), COUNT(c.user) FROM users u
INNER JOIN terrenos t on u.id = t.iduser
INNER JOIN conversas c on u.id =t.iduser
GROUP BY t.iduser
```

Comment: A sua ideia está correta, mas o segundo join com a tabela conversas que está com a referência errada: `INNER JOIN conversas c on u.id =t.iduser` deveria ser assim: `INNER JOIN conversas c on u.id =c.iduser`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode chegar a esses valores da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT      u.nome
        ,   IFNULL(t.totalterrenos, 0)  AS totalterrenos
        ,   IFNULL(c.totalconversas, 0) AS totalconversas
FROM        users   u
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      iduser
                        ,   COUNT(1) AS totalterrenos
                FROM        terrenos
                GROUP BY    iduser
            )       t ON t.iduser = u.id
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      iduser
                        ,   COUNT(1) AS totalconversas
                FROM        conversas
                GROUP BY    iduser
            )       c ON c.iduser = u.id
```

Estava a dar erro porque o campo `nome` não estava no `GROUP BY`.
A consulta nunca iria dar o resultado que esperava porque tinha dois `INNER JOIN` a duas tabelas com associações diferentes à tabela `user`, e mesmo corrigindo o `GROUP BY` não se iria conseguir contabilizar corretamente as ocorrências em cada uma das tabelas.

Comment: entendi, funciooun, só teve um porém, tem um usuario que não tem conversa, aí não apareceu na consulta, tem como fazer ele aparecer na consulta com conversas "0"?

Comment: Resposta editada para responder à sua questão. Basicamente, trocámos os _INNER JOIN_ pelos _LEFT JOIN_ e aplicámos um _ISNULL_ aos campos que podem ter valores _NULL_ (devido à falta de informação nas tabelas).

Comment: ele deu esse erro: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: Alterados os _ISNULL_ para _IFNULL_ (não sabia inicialmente que era MySQL).

Comment: show, deu certinho, só pra eu enteder, vc usou o left join e fez como se fosse uma consulta dentro da outra, isso?

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo Como sugestão, eu colocaria na pergunta (nessa e nas próximas) a tag [tag:mysql], assim todos que forem responder (ou consultar, no caso desta, que já foi respondida) já saberão de qual banco se trata.

Comment: ah blz, Obrigado!

Comment: Respondendo à sua questão @LeandroMarzullo, sim, o _LEFT JOIN_ permite obter informação das tabelas associadas tendo ou não registos associados (ao contrário do _INNER JOIN_, que "obriga" a que o _iduser_ exista em todas as tabelas ligadas), e ligamos a uma consulta direta, associando o _iduser_ dessa consulta com o iduser da tabela _users_.

Comment: show, agora entendi bem a diferença do join e do left, estou até aplicando em outras consultas aqui...rs

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver usando o `MS SQL Server` pode fazer assim:

```
select 

A.nome, 
B.terrenos,
C.conversas

from users as A

cross apply (select count(1) as terrenos from terrenos where iduser = A.id) B

cross apply (select count(1) as conversas from conversas where iduser = A.id) C
```

Teste: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c56b1/11

Comment: não, é mysql, não deu certo